# Explicit Expr constructor

Tags: julia

Accordingly to the standard function *names*, *Expr* type is said to follow this simple structure:

```
julia> names(Expr)
3-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :head
 :args
 :typ
```

Therefore, I expect to be able to build an *Expr* from a direct call of the *Expr* constructor with this following trivial method, from another *Expr*:

```
julia> exp1 = :(x+y);
julia> exp2 = Expr(exp1.head,exp1.args,exp1.typ)
:(({:+,:x,:y})(Any))
```

But the resulting exp2 does not contain the same *args* as exp1; *Expr* build the new *args* from exp1.args and exp1.typ :

```
julia> exp2.args
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 {:+,:x,:y}
 Any
```

vs

```
julia> exp1.args
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 :+
 :x
 :y
```

What did I do wrong?

***Edit:***

Following the Varargs section of the [documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/), it is also possible to splice an iterable object into a function call. So in my case, it simply goes:

```
julia> Expr(:call,exp1.args...)
:(x+y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Expr()` constructor doesn't map the inputs directly to the fields of the Expr type. Rather the first input becomes the head and the rest of the inputs become the args. So to construct the expression `x + y` using the Expr constructor you would do:

```
Expr(:call, :(+), :x, :y)
```

Comment: :(+) is equivalent to :+ is it not?

Comment: yes but in some cases the parens are safer. I don't think it matters for plus though. If you need to have a colon though you would need them `:(:)`

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I got a doubt after reading [this introduction](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/01/07/symbolic-differentiation-in-julia/) to Julia's symbolic differentiation.. Perhaps did the *Expr* constructor changed since 2013?